# How do i know which field is not matched in MYSQL Statment

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, sql

I have an issue with MYSQL statement and i just wanted to check two fields in one table whether both matched the below query is work fine but i just want know if one of these field failed to matched.how do i get to know which field is didn't match?
 Here is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `all_users`
WHERE `UserName`= 'Johne' AND
      `UserPassword` = '40bd001563085fc35165329ea1ff5c5ecbdbbeef'
```

Comment: if any one there for help

Comment: How do i Use this statement in codeigniter ? SELECT *, (UserPassword = $pass) AS UserPasswordMatch FROM all_users WHERE UserName = $Username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `OR`, not `AND` in the `WHERE` clause to include rows where only one of the columns are matched.

```
SELECT *, (`UserName`= 'Johne') AS UsernameMatch,
(`UserPassword` = '40bd001563085fc35165329ea1ff5c5ecbdbbeef') AS UserPasswordMatch
FROM `all_users`
WHERE `UserName`= 'Johne' OR `UserPassword` = '40bd001563085fc35165329ea1ff5c5ecbdbbeef';
```

Be careful what you use the result for though, as you don't want people to be able to guess that another user has the given password.

Instead you could use:

```
SELECT *, (`UserPassword` = '40bd001563085fc35165329ea1ff5c5ecbdbbeef') AS UserPasswordMatch
FROM `all_users`
WHERE `UserName`= 'Johne';
```

to check whether the password of an actual username is correct.

Comment: Perfect Mr Kilgore Thanks for the help.. Second option is what i required and again thanks for the coding. Cheers